# IntelliJ tool window toolbar - navigate using keyboard

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way to navigate to toolbar in tool window using keyboard? For example I want to use 'Refresh all Gradle plugin' (first button in gradle tool toolbar). I know that I can create custom shortcut for it, but is there any possibility to navigate to this button when I am in gradle tool window?

[image: Tool window]

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the keyboard, you can press Ctrl +Shift + A and start typing an action name (in your case, "refresh..."), then just select it from the list and press enter. 
This is also useful when you know there's an action but don't know where to look for it.